# jQuery ajax fails for unknown reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, windows-desktop-gadgets

I'm calling a function like this:

```
function(activeOnly, callback) {
    debug("$.support.cors: {0}".format($.support.cors));
    debug("getting data({0})".format(activeOnly));
    debug("{0}/data/".format(this._api_root));
    $.ajax({
        url: "{0}/data/".format(this._api_root),
        data: {
            generaldata: !activeOnly
        },
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            authorization: this._auth_header
        },
        success: function (data, code, jqx) {
            debug("data request succeeded with {0}".format(data));
            result = data;
        },
        error: function(jqx, err, ex) {
            debug("data request failed with {0}: {1}".format(err, ex));                 
        },
        complete: function(jqx, status) {
            debug("data request completed: {0}".format(status));                    
        }
    });
```

In response, the error and complete functions are called, with the resulting output:

```
[6192] MyData: $.support.cors: true
[6192] MyData: getting data({0})
[6192] MyData: https://_some_root_/data/
[6192] MyData: data request failed with Unknown: Unknown
[6192] MyData: data request completed: Unknown
```

When I monitor using Charles, this is what I get:

```
https://_some_root_/
Failed
No request was made. Possibly the certificate was rejected.
-
HTTP/1.0
CONNECT
-
/127.0.0.1
_some_root_/_some_ip_address_

3/31/11 3:15:28 PM
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
0.02 KB/s
-

366 bytes
-
-
-
366 bytes
-
-
```

and in the request tab, I can see that my request doesn't even look right (note the lack of an Authorization header):

```
CONNECT _some_root_:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; Tablet PC 2.0)
Host: _some_root_:443
Content-Length: 0
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
```

What gives?  There is no prompt for an unrecognized certificate or anything like that - it just fails.  (It works fine if I make a GET request in my browser).

Comment: can you try adding a `cache: false` in your AJAX request ?

Comment: @LekisS: I tried, and it didn't work.  No surprise there: for `dataType: "json"`, `cache` is set to false by default.

Comment: @ben is this cross-domain ajax?

Comment: try to diagnose with http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ to see what is actually send and received. seems like browser may trying to handle something else before returning to javascript context.

Comment: @kjy112 yes.  The gadget runtime is supposed to allow cross-domain requests, however.

Comment: @ertan: charles performs the same function as fiddler.  I actually tried to use fiddler, but I couldn't get it to capture SSL correctly.  Moreover, I'm not in a browser, I'm in the gadget version of the MSHTML runtime, which is based on MSIE 7.0.

Comment: have you tried jsonp as datatype?

Comment: @ben: fiddler registers it self as a proxy on windows, so all http calls (even not browser contexts) are should be captured. In fiddler options there is a capture ssl option to decode ssl calls, may be that's help to see what's going on. if cant get any result, try to temporarly disable ssl, at least you recognize where the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be [a known bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8122)

1. According to the reporter the workaround/hack is to change the jQuery source from

   ```
   jQuery.support.cors = testXHR && ( "withCredentials" in testXHR );
   ```

   to

   ```
   jQuery.support.cors = true;
   ```
2. A comment on the bug has this to say:

   > Thanks for the bug report, but this is
   >   not a jQuery bug. Windows 7 Gadgets is
   >   not a supported jQuery platform. The
   >   transports layer of new ajax is
   >   pluggable, so you should just include
   >   a custom transport that ignores normal
   >   cross-domain support (or uses
   >   XDomainRequest).
3. ...and

   > Or, more simply, set jQuery.support.cors to true in your script without hacking into jQuery ;)

Comment: Note my debug logging output, which shows just before the ajax call that `$.support.cors = true`.

Comment: @Ben Doh! Didn't see that, sorry!